# How to get user in the other service?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

i need get user in the post.service

```
    @InjectRepository(PostEntity)
    private readonly postRepository: Repository<PostEntity>,
```

not working:

```
    @InjectRepository(PostEntity, ProfileEntity)
    private readonly postRepository: Repository<PostEntity>,
    private readonly profileRepository: Repository<profileEntity>,
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably

```
@InjectRepository(PostEntity)
private readonly postRepository: Repository<PostEntity>,
@InjectRepository(ProfileEntity)
private readonly profileRepository: Repository<profileEntity>,
```

since decorators only apply to the closest thing (function, parameter, etc.)